# GStreamer; Unable to play Error: "Invalid URI \"\"."

Tags: python, pyqt5, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I am receiving this error after running a Video stream in a QtMultimedia

this is the error message

GStreamer; Unable to play - ""
Error: "Invalid URI \"\"."
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: You should be getting an error message that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last)` and ends with something like `NameError: ...` or `UnboundLocalError: ...`. Can you provide the *full* error message?

Comment: this is the error message

 d1 = threading.Thread(target=self.dep1)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: `d1 = threading ...` needs to be in a function. Just a note: Use QThreads instead of Python threads when working with QT.

Comment: Thanks @MauriceMeyer

Comment: @Kikomi 1) remove `d1 = ...`, 2) call `self.dep1()` in `__init__` of ASD and 3) remove all X.join()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is only defined (that too explicitly) only in instance methods. And class doesn't exist while it is being created.

```
class ASD(MainProg):
    # ...
    d1 = threading.Thread(target=self.dep1) # self won't be defined here.
```